# Database design: How to model a relationship where a table can belong to either of two other tables?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have three entities:

1. Course
2. Section
3. Lesson

Each "course" is made up of several "lessons".
The "lessons" inside a course, can either be categorized into "sections", or not.

So, the contents of a course could look either like this:

```
Foo Course:
    Lesson 1
    Lesson 2
    Lesson 3
    Lesson 4
```

Or like this:

```
Bar Course:
    Section 1:
        Lesson 1
        Lesson 2
    Section 2:
        Lesson 3
        Lesson 4
```

So, in other words, a course can either directly have "lessons", or it can have "sections" that in turn have "lessons".

From the other perspective, a "lessons" can either directly belong to a "course", or belong to a "section" that in turn belongs to a "course".

I'm struggling to figure out how best to implement a structure like this within a relational database.

If every "lessons" had to necessarily belong to a "section", it would be easy, I could just simply have a "Course" table, a "Section" table with a "CourseId" column, and a "Lesson" table with a "SectionId" column.

But my scenario is not as straightforward as that. A "section" can potentially exist as a middleman between a "course" and several "lessons", but it can also be absent, in which case a "course" directly has the "lessons" and no there are no "sections".

I'd appreciate any suggestions regarding how such a structure can ideally be implemented in the context of relational databases.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say perhaps that the first version actually has one `Section` with all lessons in it

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I had thought about doing that, but I don't think it's ideal, it's a little awkward. What's the purpose of a section if there is just one within an entire course? The whole point of having sections is to categorize lessons, it doesn't really make much sense if you have just one section, I mean semantically, I understand the technical utility of that though. It's like having just one "category", if you will. & since I'd have columns in the `Section` table like `Title`, etc. I'd have to put dumb values into those columns in order to create the single section, which is a bummer.

Answer (score 7):

### 1  Progress Requirement

> *a course can either directly have "lessons", or it can have "sections" that in turn have "lessons".  
> a "lessons" can either directly belong to a "course", or belong to a "section" that in turn belongs to a "course".*

1. Although you have given some rules, there are others that are implied, not explicit.  We need to make them explicit.
2. There are other considerations, which need to be evaluated and determined.  
   Eg. **What precisely, is a Lesson** ?

   - Is Lesson independent, such that it can be used in more than one course, without duplication of the Lesson ?
     `Lesson`[Safe Use of Hammer] may be in
     `Course`[Woodwork] as well as
     `CourseSection`[Carpentry, Basics]`
   - Is Lesson dependent on Course [and Section], and thus unique to that structure ?
   - I will assume the former.

Here is an interim model, showing the two types of Courses, and an independent Lesson, awaiting decisions, and further data modelling.  Duplicated elements are shown in red.
[image: Unnormalised tables, for understanding]

### 2  Relational Data Model

Forgive me if I don't show the several intermediate steps (not possible in the demanded *simple question and answer* format).  Here is the final data model.

- Normalised means no nulls in the database
- Nullable Foreign Keys are particularly bad news, strictly forbidden
- a "dummy record" is not only awkward and horrible (affects every `SELECT` that accesses the table), it is not a Fact, and it is completely unnecessary
- `RecordIds` are physical; anti-Relational, each requires an additional column and index.
  [image: Relational, Normalised]
- This uses Relational Keys (*made up from the data*), it provides Relational Integrity (as distinct from Referential Integrity)

  - `CourseLesson.CourseLesson` identifies the lesson within the course, such that it has meaning within the course, independent of the `LessonNo`
  - `SectionLesson.SectionLesson` identifies the lesson within the section, such that it has meaning within the course and section, independent of the `LessonNo`
- `Course` is an Exclusive Subtype, to ensure that:

  - a simple course `Course_TypeLesson` has lessons directly, and
  - a sectioned course `Course_TypeSection` has lessons attached to the section, not the course.
- `Lesson` is independent and fully defined (once)

  - `Lesson is used in` either type of `Course`
  - `CourseLesson.AK` prevents the `Lesson` from being duplicated within the simple `Course`
  - `SectionLesson.AK` prevents the `Lesson` from being duplicated within the sectioned `Course`.

#### More ?

The progressed data model resolves many issues, and hopefully answers your question.  But it may expose others, it may need further definition: Data Modelling is an iterative task.  Please feel free to comment.

#### Notation

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.iso.org/standard/60614.html), the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993.
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading for those who are new to the Relational Model, or its modelling method. Note that IDEF1X models are rich in detail and precision, showing all required details, whereas home-grown models, being unaware of the imperatives of the Standard, have far less definition. Which means, the notation needs to be fully understood.
- For full definition and usage considerations re Subtypes, refer to [Subtype Definition](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way to do this is to have two foreign keys on `Lesson`:**

```
CourseId null,
SectionId null
```

Then place a `CHECK` constraint on the table

```
(CourseId IS NOT NULL AND SectionId IS NULL) OR (CourseId IS NULL AND SectionId IS NOT NULL)
```

This means that either one must be present, but not both. **Don't be tempted** into placing the `CourseId` on a Lesson belonging to a Section, because this introduces a denormalization in the table: if a Section moved to a different Course, then you would need to update all the child Lessons.

---

**Strictly speaking,** you should really have a more complex design:
`Lesson` `CourseLesson` `SectionLesson`

This makes it impossible to enforce a Lesson being part of only one or the other though.

Answer (score 0):

Shift your view: if all `Course`s can have lectures, but only some lectures belongs to a section, would that solve your problem?

In concrete terms (if you want to learn don't even bother reading this :D):

`Lesson` belongs to `course`, foreign key, non-nullable.
`Lesson` has a foreign key to a `section`, nullable.

Now if `lessons` or `sections` can belong to other courses, thats a different beast.

Comment: +1 Thank you! I see one important problem with this approach though: Retrieving the lessons and their sections would potentially result in a huge dataset. Imagine a course has 100 lessons, and 25 of them belong to one section, now say I wanted to retrieve all the lessons of a certain course + the section that each of those lessons belongs to, if I run a query like that, I would get the data of that 1 section 25 times.

Comment: Another problem, which is more trivial, is that in this approach a section doesn't really belong to any course, and thus it could be used by lessons of different courses, which is not that big of a deal, but it's not ideal either. Plus, in my scenario, a course can't have sections and lessons directly at the same time. It could either directly have lessons, OR sections that have lessons, but not both. This approach doesn't establish any constraint on that. Although I'm not sure any approach can establish this constraint at the database level.

Comment: Is it? Perhaps I'm not understanding but if you mean `select * from lessons l where l.course_id = <certain course_id> join sections s on l.session_id = s.id`? I would be willing to bet there is no such educational entity on this planet that I could not run this query on my cellphone over sqlite in < 3s or something like that. But it trully depends on your needs and for that I would be glad to give you my point of view if you could materialize more your needs

Comment: As for your second question, yes, there can be if that NEEDS to be on the database. It seems more like a presentation problem than an actual data problem. The first question that I would ask is what kind of report I'll have to generate? If I can answer than with this simple schema, I would go with it. If I can't, then we make the model more complex.

Comment: Just to expand, there is technical way (SQL) to deal with this problem, if its technical problem. But that should be last resort - if there is the case where a course can't have such a setting (lesson with section and without that belongs to the same course) we may be missing a business concept.

Comment: Furthermore "a section doesn't really belong to any course, and thus it could be used by lessons of different courses", you can include a course_id foreign key on the section for sure! But then be mindful of how you are going to construct your queries/triggers in such way. The way I answered doesn't have this problem, I can do an ERD if you want but I suggest you do it yourself and make sure you get the point - but feel free to point to me if something is not right and I made a mistake there